# can't find highgui100d.dll, I searched it on the internet but found nothing

Tags: c++, visual-c++

(VS2010, Win 7 32bit)I use OpenCV in my project, When I am under Debug mode, I build the dll is short of the highgui100d.dll, but under release mode this problem doesn't exist. Now I want to debug the project, how do I solve it?

ps:I have downloaded a highgui100d.dll(844K or 840K) and added it to project, but this problem still exits. Is something wrong with the program or the dll? And the other dll is OK, under release is also OK, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this dll is in the same directory with your exe? You should put it there.
Windows will look for this dll in:

1) Inside all directories which describrs in variable PATH

2) Inside direcotry of your exe.

Comment: I found that highgui100d.dll is needed to compile with OpenCV1.0.0, and it's too old, so I updated and solve it.